# Cannot manually navigate to urls

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2012

Whenever I manually enter a url into my browser to a site built with Angular, I get:

```
'HTTP 404
 The resource cannot be found
 Requested URL: /register'
```

The only navigable url is `http://localhost:XXXX/index.html`, from there I have to navigate around the site with anchor tags.

My config file for Angular looks like this:

```
app.config(function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
//.hashPrefix('!')
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/Client/AngularViews/home.html'
    })
    .when('/register', {
        templateUrl: '/Client/AngularViews/register.html',
        controller: 'registerController'
    })
    .when('/post-register', {
        templateUrl: '/Client/AngularViews/postRegister.html',
        controller: 'registerController'
    })
    .otherwise({ templateUrl: 'Client/AngularViews/home.html' });
});
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/mainController.js"></script>
    <base href="/" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
```

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? I want to be able to manually enter urls into the address bar and navigate to anything other than index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation:

> **Server side** 
>   Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side,
>   basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your
>   application (e.g. index.html). Requiring a  tag is also
>   important for this case, as it allows Angular to differentiate between
>   the part of the url that is the application base and the path that
>   should be handeled by the application.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

So you need some additional support from server-side: configure your http server to reply with `index.html` for all url you have in your apps.

Answer (score 1):

I use ASP.Net MVC for server side URL rewriting using controllers. Probably not its intended use but works well